# How to set the values of Tfidf Model in gensim manually

Tags: python, gensim, tf-idf

In the Python code:

```
tfidf = models.TfidfModel(corpus)
corpus_tfidf = tfidf[corpus]
```

I want to find a way to fill the values of the `corpus_tfidf` manually as I already have a list of lists of tfidfs for each document in the corpus, calculated using specific equations.

So, how to use them to fill the `corpus_tfidf` instead of recalculating them using `gensim` calculations.

I want to use my values to be passed for the `gensim` LSI and LDA models.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that if you can manually assign the `idfs` attribute, then you should be able to transform a corpus without re-fitting. Hope this helps.

Self-contained example:

```
from gensim.models import TfidfModel
from gensim.corpora import Dictionary

# trained version
corpus = ['cow', 'brown thing', 'cow thing']
corpus = [x.split() for x in corpus]
dct = Dictionary(corpus)
corpus_as_bow = [dct.doc2bow(x) for x in corpus]
model_trained = TfidfModel(corpus_as_bow)
corpus_tfidf_trained = model_trained[corpus_as_bow]

# not trained version
model_not_trained = TfidfModel()
model_not_trained.idfs = {0: 0.5849625007211562, 1: 1.5849625007211563, 2: 0.5849625007211562}
corpus_tfidf_not_trained = model_not_trained[corpus_as_bow]

# check equivalence
list(corpus_tfidf_trained) == list(corpus_tfidf_not_trained)
```

> True

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpful reply. One more step to get the answer is to assign the values of the tfids instead of the idfs. The data I already have is the tfidfs, and they are computed using C# and saved as List of Lists. They are computed using specific reserch equations and I want to use them to pass to the LSI and LDA. I don't want to get the standard tfidfs computed by gensim.

Comment: @AyaZoghby Hi. Did you find any way to set tf-idf values??